# Is this the right way to return a struct in a parameter?

Tags: c++, struct, reference

I made the following method in a C++/CLI project:

```
void GetSessionData(CDROM_TOC_SESSION_DATA& data)
{
    auto state = CDROM_TOC_SESSION_DATA{};

    // ...

    data = state;
}
```

Then I use it like this in another method:

```
CDROM_TOC_SESSION_DATA data;
GetSessionData(data);
// do something with data
```

It does work, returned `data` is not garbage, however there's something I don't understand.

**Question:**

C++ is supposed to clean up `state` when it has exitted its scope, so `data` is a copy of `state`, correct ?

And in what exactly it is different from the following you see on many examples:

```
CDROM_TOC_SESSION_DATA data;
GetSessionData(&data); // signature should be GetSession(CDROM_TOC_SESSION_DATA *data)
```

Which one makes more sense to use or is the right way ?

**Reference:**

[CDROM_TOC_SESSION_DATA](https://learn.microsoft.com/is-is/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddcdrm/ns-ntddcdrm-_cdrom_toc_session_data)

Comment: Note: Neither of these returns a struct.  They accept a reference/pointer to a struct as a parameter and then modify it.

Comment: okay but do not take it literally, the method *returns* something, *somehow*...

Comment: it doesn't though. It _modified data_.  The equivalent would be if you gave me an address, and then I went to the address and built a house there.  I didn't _give_ you a house, I just built one at the one you gave me the address for. And hoped you owned that address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a reference vs a pointer for an out parameter is really more of a matter of style.  Both function equally well, but some people feel that the explicit `&` when calling a function makes it more clear that the function may modify the parameter it was passed.

i.e.

```
doAThing(someObject);
// It's not clear that doAThing accepts a reference and
// therefore may modify someObject
```

vs

```
doAThing(&someObject);
// It's clear that doAThing accepts a pointer and it's
// therefore possible for it to modify someOjbect
```

---

Note that 99% of the time the correct way to return a class/struct type is to just `return` it.  i.e.:

```
MyType getObject()
{
    MyType object{};

    // ...

    return object;
}
```

Called as

```
auto obj = getObject();
```

---

In the specific case of `CDROM_TOC_SESSION_DATA` it likely makes sense to use an out parameter, since the class contains a flexible array member.  That means that the parameter is almost certainly a reference/pointer to the beginning of some memory buffer that's larger than `sizeof(CDROM_TOC_SESSION_DATA)`, and so must be handled in a somewhat peculiar way.

Answer (score 2):

> C++ is supposed to clean up state when it has exitted its scope, so
>   data is a copy of state, correct ?

In the first example, the statement

```
data = state
```

presumably copies the value of `state` into local variable `data`, which is a reference to the same object that is identified by `data` in the caller's scope (because those are the chosen names -- they don't *have* to match).  I say "presumably" because in principle, an overridden assignment operator could do something else entirely.  In any library you would actually want to use, you can assume that the assignment operator does something sensible, but it may be important to know the details, so you should check.

The lifetimes of local variables `data` and `state` end when the method exits.  They will be cleaned up at that point, and no attempt may be made to access them thereafter.  None of that affects the caller's `data` object.

> And in what exactly it is different from the following you see on many
>   examples:
>
> ```
> CDROM_TOC_SESSION_DATA data;
> GetSessionData(&data);
> ```

Not much.  Here the caller passes a pointer instead of a reference.  `GetSessionData` must be declared appropriately for that, and its implementation must explicitly dereference the pointer to access the caller's `data` object, but the general idea is the same for most intents and purposes.  Pointer and reference are similar mechanisms for indirect access.

> Which one makes more sense to use or is the right way ?

It depends.  Passing a reference is generally a bit more idiomatic in C++, and it has the advantage that the method does not have to worry about receiving a null or invalid pointer.  On the other hand, passing a pointer is necessary if the function has C linkage, or if you need to accommodate the possibility of receiving a null pointer.